# Opening, parsing, and saving a copy of a large txt or xml file (6gb)

Tags: xml, vba, parsing

I'm trying to open a large (6gb) txt/xlm file, parse it, and save the parsed information to a new and much smaller file.  At its simplest, I have an xml file similar to...

```
<cat>
<a1>a</a1>
<b1>b</b1>
</cat>
<cat>
<a1>x</a1>
<b1>y</b1>
<c1>z</c1>
</cat>
<cat>
<a1>aa</a1>
<b1/>
<c1>cc</c1>
</cat>
<cat>
<a1></a1>
<b1>GG</b1>
<c1>HH</c1>
</cat>
```

...and I want to parse it to...

```
a  | b  |
x  | y  | z
aa |    | cc
   | GG | HH
```

I'm doing okay with the parsing (although I may ask questions later).  My main issue is handling the large 6gb file.

I can open, manipulate, and save files up to about 30mb.  After that, Excel dies.  Somewhere after 50mb I start getting code errors saying, "File already open".  SO MY QUESTION IS, HOW CAN I WORK WITH THIS REALLY LARGE FILE (6gb)?  I know VBA isn't the best way, but I haven't found text editors that will load the file and MS app's like Access crap out at around 2gb.  Would running the VBA in an application other than Excel work better?  Would using the FSO on an .asp page work better?  I'm stumped.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance,
Andrew

Here is a simplified version of the code I have been trying:

```
Public Sub atest()
    Dim filePath As String
    Dim breakIdentity As String
    Dim piece As String
    Dim newFilePath As String
    Dim strIn As String
    Dim lineCtr As Long
    filePath = Sheets("Parse").Range("A2").Value
        newFilePath = Replace(filePath, ".txt", "-ReFormatted.txt")
        Open filePath For Input As #1
        Open newFilePath For Output As #2 'HERE IS WHERE I GET FILE ALREADY OPEN ERRORS ON LARGE FILES
    Do While Not EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, strIn
        If Len(strIn) > 1 Then
            lineCtr = lineCtr + 1
            If InStr(strIn, breakIdentity) <> 0 And lineCtr > 1 Then
                Print #2, strIn
                Debug.Print strIn
            End If
        End If
    Loop
    Close #1
    Close #2
    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Here is an example of the txt/xml...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TagValidationList>
<TVLHeader>
  <SubmissionType>STVL</SubmissionType>
  <SubmissionDateTime>2017-10-02T01:03:15Z</SubmissionDateTime>
  <SSIOPHubID>9002</SSIOPHubID>
  <HomeAgencyID>9002</HomeAgencyID>
  <BulkIndicator>B</BulkIndicator>
  <BulkIdentifier>32</BulkIdentifier>
  <RecordCount>15482798</RecordCount>
</TVLHeader>
<TVLDetail>
<TVLTagDetails>
  <HomeAgencyID>0041</HomeAgencyID>
  <TagAgencyID>1110</TagAgencyID>
  <TagSerialNumber>01234567</TagSerialNumber>
  <TagStatus>V</TagStatus>
  <TagClass>2</TagClass>
  <TVLPlateDetails>
    <PlateCountry>US</PlateCountry>
    <PlateState>TX</PlateState>
    <PlateNumber>ABC123</PlateNumber>
    <PlateEffectiveFrom>2010-09-09T15:57:05Z</PlateEffectiveFrom>
  </TVLPlateDetails>
  <TVLAccountDetails>
    <AccountNumber>7654321</AccountNumber>
  </TVLAccountDetails>
</TVLTagDetails>
<TVLTagDetails>
  <HomeAgencyID>0041</HomeAgencyID>
  <TagAgencyID>1110</TagAgencyID>
  <TagSerialNumber>21234567</TagSerialNumber>
  <TagStatus>V</TagStatus>
  <TagType>S</TagType>
  <TagClass>2</TagClass>
  <TVLPlateDetails>
    <PlateCountry>US</PlateCountry>
    <PlateState>TX</PlateState>
    <PlateNumber>BBC123</PlateNumber>
    <PlateEffectiveFrom>2010-09-09T16:14:43Z</PlateEffectiveFrom>
  </TVLPlateDetails>
  <TVLAccountDetails>
    <AccountNumber>6543210</AccountNumber>
  </TVLAccountDetails>
</TVLTagDetails>
<TVLTagDetails>
  <HomeAgencyID>0041</HomeAgencyID>
  <TagAgencyID>1110</TagAgencyID>
  <TagSerialNumber>31234567</TagSerialNumber>
  <TagStatus>V</TagStatus>
  <TagClass>2</TagClass>
  <TVLPlateDetails>
    <PlateCountry>US</PlateCountry>
    <PlateState>TX</PlateState>
    <PlateNumber>CBC123</PlateNumber>
    <PlateEffectiveFrom>2010-09-09T15:58:15Z</PlateEffectiveFrom>
  </TVLPlateDetails>
  <TVLAccountDetails/>
</TVLTagDetails>
</TVLDetail>
</TagValidationList>
```

Comment: If its a valid xml file, you should look to use a proper xml parser (preferable SAX parser for large files). You can also use XSLT to transform the xml to generate required output.

Comment: Maybe using SQL Server Express is an option. See: https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/sql-server/sql-server-editions-express. You should be able to import the whole data set with this and analyze it much easier.

Comment: I can't guarantee that the XML is properly formatted.  My partner has tried a couple of parsers and they declare that the file is not properly formatted.  We don't know if that is because of the file size or the formatting.  I'll check if he has tried SAX.  The coding required for SAX is beyond my abilities.

I've briefly looked at XSLT.  Will it handle a file size of 6gb?

Comment: Thank you.  I'm taking a look into SQL Server Express now.  Regarding XSLT, even if it transforms the file neatly, I still have to export it as a text file.  Wouldn't that pose the same issues with file size that I have now?

Comment: You could split that file into smaller more-manageable files and then parse the smaller files to get the content.

Comment: Yes Tim, but then we're looking at about 200 individual files.That's not really a repeatable process.  Also, we've not found a text editor that will reliably open the large file.  If anyone knows of a text editor that will open the file, please let me know.  That would help tremendously.

Comment: I wasn't implying you do the splitting manually: you could use VBA to read line-by-line and create the files programmatically.

Comment: Ah, thanks Tim.  Doing that would be great, but then I'm back to where I've been with my current code.  It dies when trying to read anything over about 30mb.  I sure wouldn't mind parsing it into smaller files, if that's what it takes.  We can merge them into Access programmatically afterwards.  I'm just stuck on reading the large file line-by-line.  Is there another method besides the one I've given above?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.  I abandoned the VBA route.  It looked like it was never going to be able to handle the large file.  I went with the DB route and successfully imported the large XML file into a single column single row table where I've been able to query and generate a much more streamlined flat (TXT) file.  I used the process found at the URL [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2899/importing-and-processing-data-from-xml-files-into-sql-server-tables/).

Thanks again,
Andrew